# Serel: A Ruby Library with full support for API 2.0

Tags: library, api-v2, ruby

### Getting Started?

> **Visit http://serel.tom.is for a whirlwind tour of the library**.

<sup>although it is still very much a tour in progress</sup>

### About

Serel is Stack Exchange RElational Algebra, a fully featured Ruby library for the Stack Exchange API. With a public API inspired by Arel, the query engine behind Active Record, Serel aims to provide easy and complete access to the Stack Exchange API.

#### License

MIT License

#### Download

`gem install serel`

Alternatively, find Serel on [RubyGems](http://rubygems.org/gems/serel). A quick tour and introduction can be found on the [Serel site](http://serel.tom.is).

#### Platform

Ruby 1.9+ is required to run Serel.

### Contact

Comment me. Or ping me on chat. I'm usually in The Bridge.

### Code

You can find the code on [GitHub](http://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/serel), as well as documentation generated off the master branch on [RDoc](http://rdoc.info/github/thomas-mcdonald/serel), even if it is lacklustre in places.

Automatic builds are done with [Travis-Ci](http://travis-ci.org/thomas-mcdonald/serel), and the current build status of master is: [image: Build Status].

Written in Ruby, with test suite assistance from RSpec, Webmock & VCR.

Contributions are more than welcome, since I'm sure I'll have misplaced something somewhere.

#### Roadmap

- Native support for caching
- Identity map to avoid repeat requests

#### Changelog

**10/4/2012** - 1.0.0

- Better handling of dates.
- Allow `#get` to get without overwriting the scoped URL

**29/2/2012** - 1.0.0.rcx

- Release

Comment: Is this library still supported/maintained?

Answer (score 5):

We ([myself](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/1346/jason-salaz) and [Kyle](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/13/kyle-cronin)), with graphical help from [Nathan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/2220/nathan-greenstein), developed an automatically generated image that pulls in the number of bounties, the total bounty rep value, and displays that in an image.

[image: Current Ask Different bounties]

It is part of the [Ask Different Community Ads](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/998/1346), and we're pretty proud of it.

Thanks for developing Serel, it made the heavy lifting of StackExchange's API insanely simple, and we could focus on the harder parts, like getting RMagick to play nice and actually do what we want it to do (`┬──┬ ლ(ಠ益ಠლ)` adequately explains how I felt about RMagick... often).

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to be broken in the HTTPS-era of SE?

Answer (score 1):

Nice work! I look forward to the day I don't have to install it with `--pre`! :D

I'm using this library as the backend to a project that you might hear about in the not so distant future. Just have to work out some logistical / hosting / etc. issues.

Comment: that day is now here!